# Create a separate view

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

I am creating a webapp using the MVC pattern to structure the client side javascript.   There are  three separate pages, so I have three separate views connecting to the a single model.

I would like to be able to initiate view's without them knowing about each other.  For example, if I click on a photo in one of the views, it should open a light-box view.

Should the model be responsible for deciding which view gets instantiated?

Answer (score 0):

I would let the controller do that task.

Basically:

- ***Model***: Data.
- ***View***: Present data and let user modify data.
- ***Controller***: Link Model with View.